# creating variables from a URL value string like you would with $_GET

Tags: php, variables, get

How can I get the create the variables with the values out of this *string*, similar to how you would with `$_GET`

```
search=test&site=1&salesperson=2&referral=6&product=10&estimate=1000&sort=date&open=on&filter_sbmt=Filter+Prospect&limit=30
```

**e.g.**

```
$search = 'test';
$site = 1;
etc...
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Please reformulate.

Comment: yes, that looks like what I want, but how do you set the variables after parse?

Comment: u just do it manually? 
parse_str($str, $val_arr);

$search = $val_arr['search'];

or could you do it with a script?

Comment: Simply dumping the variables into the current scope is usually a _very bad idea_. Is there a particular reason that you can't just use the array?

Comment: So would this be ideal? `foreach($val_arr as $l=>$v) {
 ${$l} = $v;
}'

Comment: $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

// Recommended
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

you also can use for each on this array to get key and value

Comment: dear @Source , why have you downgraded my solution because it is exactly what you asked for, you wanted the variables in the same way you would get them with $_GET. GET gives you a array, my solution gives you also a array and you can access each variable with $arr['search'] , the way you would access with $_GET['search']

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_str()` function (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-parse_str-function/)

```
$str = 'search=test&site=1&salesperson=2&referral=6&product=10&estimate=1000&sort=date&open=on&filter_sbmt=Filter+Prospect&limit=30';
parse_str($str);
echo $search; // 'test'
echo $site; // '1'
```

Don't try to make this call without storing the result on an array, this is discouraged and deprecated as of PHP 7.2 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

You have then to pass a result object to store the results on as a second parameter:

```
$str = 'search=test&site=1&salesperson=2&referral=6&product=10&estimate=1000&sort=date&open=on&filter_sbmt=Filter+Prospect&limit=30';
$output = array();
parse_str($str, $output);
print_r($output); // Array ( [search] => test [site] => 1 ...)
echo $output['search']; // 'test'
echo $output['site']; // '1'
```